# Why doesn't this Elektor ramp circuit work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, circuit-design, fault

I built the following circuit on my breadboard, it is from an old Elektor article:

[image]

It is a ramp generator that repeatedly

1. charges C3 through the dual-PNP current mirror to build a ramp, and
2. briefly shorts C3 across T1 to reset the ramp & the cycle (triggered by the rising front of the square wave input, differentiated through C2/R2).

The fundamental frequency of the output signal matches that of the control signal.  It is an evolution on a simpler circuit presented in the same article that generates log-shapped ramps as opposed to linear ones.  I have successfully built the simpler version on my breadboard. Differences compared to the schematic above are

1. the current mirror is just a plain 10k resistor,
2. it does not have the FET output stage,
3. there is a 10k resistor between the input signal and its connection to C1/C2, and
4. C4 is 1μF and C3 is 180nF.

The rest of the topology is identical (see page 113 [here](https://worldradiohistory.com/UK/Elektor/80s/Elektor-301Circuits-79-179.pdf), i.e. pdf page 21). I generate the input square wave with an MCU so the it's about 3.3V peak-to -peak (TTL) instead of 4V.

C4' and D1 are optional and not needed in my use-case so I breadboarded the circuit with wires instead of those.  I laid it out on the breadboard twice from scratch using brand new components each time, but no luck. It does not produce the specified output waveform. I am using all the same parts as specified on the schematic except

1. I use non-graded BC5x7s instead of the two hfe-graded BC5x7Bs, and
2. the E300 is obsolete so I replaced it with a BF256B.

I have tried powering it with a regulated 5V supply available on the development board, as well as a 9V battery. Both Vcc & common ground hookup wires heat up significantly when the power is on (the more power, the mores so). I have checked and re-checked my layout for shorts but all seems fine.

Per comments below, I measured the current draw on the VCC rail: 900mA @ 5V, 1.3A @ 9V. (By contrast, the simpler topology draws about 320nA, if my multimeter is to be trsted for such low values -- I'm not sure, but not much anyway.)  So it does look like a short, I guess the path VCC > T4 > T1 > GND has a fairly low resistance?

Also per comments, I put in a 3.3uF cap at C4' instead of wire. (The article recommends "no more than 4.7", no unit stated but it's electrolytic so I thought that should be right.) Current draw reduced to 500mA @ 5V, 900mA @ 9V.  Again, I don't need capacitance for my use case so then I also tried a 10kΩ in that position. Current draw measurements were in the same regions as with a 3.3uF cap.

In every case though, the output is a fixed voltage (no signal) between 1.5V and 2V depending on the arrangements. **Any idea what's wrong with the topology, or what I am doing wrong with it?**

Comment: Sounds like you are shorting out the power supply somehow. Measure the resistance from VCC to GND. Measure the current taken (should only be a few mA at a guess)

Comment: Show us a pic of your breadboarded circuit.

Comment: You have enough series resistors with enough value so transistor saturation is not likely. Even the JFET has a 4.7 K source resistor, so no heat there. You have a short that bypasses a resistor or capacitor.

Comment: How did you "leave out" C4'?  If you replaced it with a wire, then that's your problem.

Comment: Yes I had a wire at C4'.  I measured the current draw on the VCC rail like that, with a 3.3uF cap, and with a 10kΩ in that position.  By contrast, the simpler topology draws about 320nA, if my multimeter is to be trsted for such low values -- I'm not sure, but not much anyway. In every case the output is a steady voltage (no signal) always between 1.5V and 2V but shifting a little depending on the arrangements.  I edited my question to reflect these findings.

Comment: **Remove** C4`.  Put **nothing** in its place.

Comment: If you had a wire in place of C4', then T1 and T4 are probably toast.  That wire caused a short straight through them both.  The constantly high current says that.

Comment: And T3 is toast, too.